# R RVEST: Finding a correct Xpath to extract info from a webpage

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, rvest

I am currently trying to extract data from a webpage and my code has not been working.
This is the webpage [(https://www.fao.org/faolex/results/details/en/c/LEX-FAOC213092)](https://www.fao.org/faolex/results/details/en/c/LEX-FAOC213092)
and i want to extract from this page the information in the table below and create a table with the variables (language, date, type of text, keywords..etc.).
Ideally, i would be able to then later iterate across other webpages and append the data.
Here is the code i've tried but so far has only given me empty or NAs.

```
extract_info <- function(url) {
  page <- read_html(url)  

  # Extract source (available website)
  source <- page %>%
    html_node( '.item-value > a') %>%
    html_attr("href")
  # Replace missing summary with an empty string
    #source <- if_else(is.na(source), "", source)
    
  # Extract type of text (policy/legislation)
  text_type <- page %>%
    html_node('.item-text:nth-child(1) .item-value')%>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE) 
  
  # Replace missing text_type with an empty string
 # text_type <- if_else(is.na(text_type), "", text_type)

  # Extract language of document
  language <- page %>%
    html_node(xpath= '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "documentLanguage", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "item-value", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE) 

  
  
  # Extract date of text
  date <- page %>%
    html_node(xpath='///*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "dateOfText", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "item-value", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE) 


  # Extract key words
  keywords <- page %>%
   html_nodes(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "keywords", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "item-value", " " ))]') %>%
  html_text(trim = TRUE) %>%
 str_trim() 
  
  # Extract domain
  domain <- page %>%
    html_node(xpath='//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "domain", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "item-value", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE)  
  
  # Extract primary subject
  primary_subject <- page %>%
    html_node(xpath= '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "primarysubject", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "item-value", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE)

  # Extract FAOLEX number
  faolex_number <- page %>%
    html_node(xpath= '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "faolexid", " " ))]//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " " ), concat( " ", "item-value", " " ))]') %>%
    html_text(trim = TRUE) 

  
  
  # Create a data frame with the extracted information
  data <- tibble(
    Source = source,
    TextType = text_type,
    Language = language,
    Date = date,
    Keywords = keywords,
    Domain = domain,
    PrimarySubject = primary_subject,
    FAOLEXNumber = faolex_number
  )
  
  return(data)
}


url<-"https://www.fao.org/faolex/results/details/en/c/LEX-FAOC213092"
info <- extract_info(url)
```

I am using Selectorgadget to get the Xpath. I tried first with copying Xpath from the HTML code but i didn't get an output either.

Comment: use xpath as for example to get the country: //*[contains(@class,'country')]//*[contains(@class,'item-value')]

Comment: thank you! it seems that the problem was that the webpage loads dynamically and i need to use RSelenium